# Post Form MVC with List of List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

Most of the Tutorials, Questions I found online where about when the Model has one List of Items. But In my Case I have a List of Items which further have a List of Items.

I have a ViewModel with List of `ItemA`, and `ItemA` has a list of `ItemsB`

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        List<ItemA> Items { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Items = new List<ItemA>();
        }
    }

    public class ItemA
    {
        public int ItemAId { get; set; }
        public List<ItemB> ItemBList { get; set; }

        public ItemA()
        {
            ItemBList = new List<ItemB>();
        }
    }

    public class ItemB
    {
        public int ItemBId { get; set; }

// Need to input this string for each Item in List<ItemA>
        public string NewInput 

    }
```

My View:

```
@Html.BeginForm(){

@foreach (var itemA in Model.Items)
{
    <p>@itemA.ItemAId</p>


    for (int i = 0; i < itemA.ItemBList.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => itemA.ItemBList[i].ItemBId )

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => itemA.ItemBList[i].NewInput)

    }
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
}

}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveInfo(ViewModel model){
// Update
}
```

My Question is how do I write a Form for this Case so it binds back to ViewModel in Controller?

Comment: There is no postback mechanism in MVC.

Comment: use for loop for it.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I am using for loop, I am getting NULL

Comment: Do you actually have any ItemB records associated with ItemA Records?

Comment: Could you tell me how you want it to look like? I mean - what's the UI? Can user select one item A or single item B or maybe multiple elements? Maybe it's a place for the cascade drop down lists? Please describe it more precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its fairly simple - you just need to nest 2 `for` loops in the view (don't use foreach)

ie change to:

```
@Html.BeginForm(){

@for(int j = 0; j < Model.Items.Count; j++)
{
    <p>@Model.Items[j].ItemAId</p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[j].ItemAId)  
    @* (don't forget this!) *@


    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items[j].ItemBList.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[j].ItemBList[i].ItemBId )

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[j].ItemBList[i].NewInput)

    }

}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

The MVC Model Binder requires form fields representing properties in lists to be named something like `[#].property1name`, `[#].property2name` in order to properly associate them to each other during binding after postback. Same principle applies to list properties of listitems. You need to use a `for` loop rather than a `foreach` loop to get the right form field names when using HTML helpers!

Comment: @James S Seems to be working in my test Project. Thanks