# Parent model have 2 properties one comes null on Add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a ParentModel because i want to use two models inside this so that i can use the same in view in MVC.

When i get the data on initial load both properties defined in Parent model populate properly.
However, when I try to add new data I see second property as null.
Here is my code :

```
public class UserModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }        
    public IEnumerable<RolesModel> rolesModel { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Add(UserModel userDetails)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            userDetails.User.FullName = userDetails.User.FirstName + " " + userDetails.User.MiddleName + " " + userDetails.User.LastName;
            userDetails.User.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            _userService.Insert(userDetails.User);
            _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();
            foreach (RolesModel rolesModel in userDetails.rolesModel)
            {
                // Here userdetails.rolesmodel is null
            }
        }
```

View :

```
@model Axp.Gcst.Gps.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.UserModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "user", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Partial("_UserDetails", Model)
    @foreach (var itemRole in Model.rolesModel)
    {                          
        if (itemRole.Role.RoleGroupId == item.RoleGroupId)
        {
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 panel_cell">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => itemRole.isSelected, new { @class = "panel_checkbox" })
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => itemRole.Role.Name)
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>itemRole.Role.RoleId)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post back a List Back to controller you should use a for loop:

```
@foreach (var itemRole in Model.rolesModel)
{
    if (itemRole.Role.RoleGroupId == item.RoleGroupId)
    {

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => itemRole.isSelected, new { @class = "panel_checkbox" })
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => itemRole.Role.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => itemRole.Role.RoleId)
    }
}
```

Use a For loop:

```
@for(int i =0; i< Model.rolesModel.Count; i++){
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.rolesModel[i].isSelected, new { @class = "panel_checkbox" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.rolesModel[i].Role.Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.rolesModel[i].Role.RoleId)

}
```

A similar Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27926181/1910735

The MVC Model Binder Requires the Input fields to be in the format:

```
list[0].prop1
list[0].prop2
list[0].prop3

list[1].prop1
list[1].prop2
list[1].prop3
```

Comment: Thanks.if (model => Model.rolesModel[i].Role.RoleGroupId == tblTestList[j].RoleGroupId) thi sline gives error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: model => Model        should be           model => model.rolesModel

Comment: why do you need **model =>** in the if condition?

Comment: Just do: if(Model.rolesModel[i].Role.RoleGroupId == tblTestList[j].RoleGroupId)