# How do I post form data with a list of list?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to save a list of lists, where I have a checkbox containing some options where are multiple choices. I'm getting the first list just fine, but the "children" prop always comes back as null.

Most solutions on the internet says that the index must be set in the list, but I have not been successful with it.

I saw someone had a similar issue: [Post Form MVC with List of List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925865/post-form-mvc-with-list-of-list)

But have not been able to make use of it, so I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

ViewModel

```
 public class Input
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool value { get; set; }
        public List<Input> children { get; set; }


        public Input()
        {
            children = new List<Input>();
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Services()
        {
            var Inputs = new List<Input>() {
                    new Input(){title="test",id=1 },
                    new Input(){title="test2",id=2,
                        children =new List<Input>(){
                        new Input(){title="test3",id=3 },
                        new Input(){title="test4",id=4 }
                    } },
                };

            return View(Inputs);
        }
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Services(List<Input> model)
        {
            return Redirect("/");

        }
```

View

```
@model List<Input>;
 <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Services" method="post">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].title)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].children)
                         <div class="checkbox">
                             <label class="form-check-label">
                                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].value, new { @class = "form-check-input collapser" })
                                 @Model[i].title
                                 <span class="form-check-sign">
                                     <span class="check"></span>
                                 </span>
                             </label>
                         </div>
                        if(Model[i].children != null){
                            string containerName = "["+i+"].value" + "Container";
                            <div name="@containerName">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                @for (int c = 0; c < Model[i].children.Count; c++){
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].children[c].title)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].children[c].id)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].children[c].children)
                                     <label class="form-check-label">
                                         @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].children[c].value, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                                         @Model[i].children[c].title
                                         <span class="form-check-sign">
                                             <span class="check"></span>
                                         </span>
                                     </label>
                                }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the browser's developer tools(press F12) to check the Form Data of the Request Headers in Network , the problem arises in the consistency of model bindings , try to comment out the below code lines:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].children)

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].children[c].children)
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thank you very much :D