# DataTables MVC on Postback the data is null

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatables, datatables-1.10

I was using MVC table to initially display the data to the user but because the data was quite large and started throwing `storage out of memory` exception, i decided to switch to `DataTables`. The data is displayed fine but on the postback, no data is coming over to the HTTPPost action method. I understand that MVC View had hidden views to store the values and during the postback they bind the model but how will we replicate this behaviour with a datatable?

thank you

```
@model IList<ViewModels.ReferralViewModel>@model IList<ViewModels.ReferralViewModel>

@{
    Layout = "";
}

@if (Model != null)
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var editor;
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,

            "order": [[1, 'asc']],
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/SMS/ReferralDetailsTest",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "json"
            },
            'columnDefs': [{
                'targets': 0,
                'searchable': false,
                'orderable': false,
                'className': 'dt-body-center',
                'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" name="IsSelected[]">';
                }
            },
                {
                    'targets': 17,
                    'data': null,
                    'defaultContent': "<input type=\"text\" size=\"100\" style = \"width: 95px; padding: 6px 2px 6px 2px\" >"
                },
                {
                    'targets': 19,
                    'data': null,
                    'defaultContent': "<input type=\"button\" value=\"SMS\" class=\"btn btn - primary\" onclick=\"return $('#sendSMS').click();\" />"
                }
            ],
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": '',
                    "className": 'select-checkbox',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "title": "Select All"
                },
                { "title": "Referral Id", "data": "ReferralId", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "First Name", "data": "patient.PatientFirstName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Last Name", "data": "patient.PatientLastName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Referral Date", "data": "ReferralDate", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Referral Priority", "data": "ReferralPriority", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Referral HospCode", "data": "ReferralHospCode", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Referral Specialty Code", "data": "ReferralSpecialtyCode", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Referral Specialty Name", "data": "ReferralSpecialtyName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Referral Clinic Code", "data": "ReferralClinicCode", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Referral Clinic Description", "data": "ReferralClinicDescription", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Last Booked Clinic Category Code", "data": "LastBookedClinicCategoryCode", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Last Booked Clinic Category", "data": "LastBookedClinicCategory", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Last Booked Clinic Code", "data": "LastBookedClinicCode", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Last Booked Clinic Description", "data": "LastBookedClinicDescription", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Mobile No", "data": "patient.MobileNumber", "autoWidth": true },
                { "title": "Overwrite Mobile No", "data": null },
                { "title": "Status", "data": "Status", "autoWidth": true }
            ],

            "select": {
                "style": 'os',
                "selector": 'td:first-child'
            }
        });
    </script>


    <div class="form-group">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="DetailsTab">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Referral" aria-controls="Referral" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="tbs">Referrals</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Responses" aria-controls="Response" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="tbs">Responses</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Referral">
                <br />


            </div>

            <div>
                <table class="table table-striped" id="example"></table>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

--Code for post method--

```
      $('#sendSMS').click(function () {
     var formData = $('#sendSMSForm').serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/SMS/SendSMSForClients",
                        data: formData, //if you need to post Model data, use this
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#partial").html("");
                            $("#partial").html(result);

                            searchReferrals(referralSpecialty, referralClinicName, referralClinicCode, referralPriority, referralStartDate, referralEndDate);
                            $('.nav-tabs a[href="#patientsReferral"]').tab('show');
                            $('.tab-pane a[href="#patientsReferral"]').tab('show');
                            $("#loading").hide();
                        },
                         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            $("#partial").html("");
                            $('#partial').html('<p>status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>' + jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                            console.log('jqXHR:');
                            console.log(jqXHR);
                            console.log('textStatus:');
                            console.log(textStatus);
                            console.log('errorThrown:');
                             console.log(errorThrown);

                        },
                    });
```

}

Comment: as you are rendering a list in the data table , you need to render each input with an Index - see this question to POST a list of values to the Controller (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925865/post-form-mvc-with-list-of-list)

Comment: second point is we don't see the Form element - look into @Html.BeginForm() - MVC model binder will bind data which is inside a Form element (also no submit button - how do you POST data to server)?

Comment: Hi @Baahubali, can you please include your code for the Post Action method?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are perhaps still thinking about Webforms and it's ViewState.
With webforms you load data to an object, that data is then stored in a hidden input and send back to the server on a form post (PostBack).

But MVC does not retain the state. So even after a form is posted you will need to reload all the data again from the database and send it to the model. Otherwise the object will be null.

WEBFORMS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //load the data from a source
    DataTable dt = LoadFromDB();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //bind data to an object
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff here on form post (PostBack)

    //you don't have to rebind data to GridView1 here since the data is retained in ViewState 
}
```

MVC

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel();

    //load the data from a source
    model.dt = LoadFromDB();

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    //do stuff here on form post

    //load the data again since it is not retained in a ViewSate
    //if you do not then dt will be null
    model.dt = LoadFromDB();

    return View(model);
}
```

On a side note, if your dataset is so large it throws a memory exception, you might want to thing about some form of paging instead of dumping all the data to the client.

Comment: may be i am not clear but before you call LoadFromDB() function, you are receiving the MyModel object from the Post or submit which is what i am after and is always null.

Comment: That is what i'm trying to say. It is null because it is not send with a PostBack. Only input controls that are bound to the properties are send to the server, usually like this `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)`. Thaty is why you need to load the data again.

Comment: yes but then in the data tables, i have a input type of checkbox and a textbox, and i need these two fields posted back. however, they are all coming as null.

Comment: If you create those inputs yourself I guess you can get the values with `Request.Form`

Comment: if you see my question, i have already provided the code which contains the input elements. during the postback there is no data including in the request.form.